# Шахматная доска (консоль). C++

Tags: c++, циклы

Пытаюсь нарисовать шахматную доску в консоли с помощью цикла, но есть одна проблема, клеточки рисуются в столбик, помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему, вот код:

```
cout << "Доска: " << endl;
for (int pos = 0; pos < 64; pos++)
{
    if (pos % 2 == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
                cout << endl;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну а как же, если после каждых пяти символов в коде происходит переход на следующую строку?

Раз Вам нужно поле 8x8 с клетками в 5 символов, печатайте 40 строк, в каждой по 40 символов, а конкретный символ определяется позицией `line/5` и `column/5` - чётностью их суммы (или ксора)

```
for (int line = 0; line < 40; line++)    {
    for (int column = 0; column < 40; column++) {
        if ((line/5+column/5)&1)
            std::cout << "*";
        else    
            std::cout << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;   
}
```

Comment: А что за амперсанд в строке `cout << (line/5 + column/5) & 1? "*":" "`? Visual ругается.

Comment: Там надо не `&`, а `&&`

Comment: Побитовое И....

Comment: Хех, действительно компилятор не понимает в тройном операторе, что нужно делать (точнее, я ему недостаточно ясно подсказываю), так что на простой if переделал.

Comment: @MBo Спасибо за помощь!